# Crop general path in Java 2D

Tags: java, awt, 2d, java-2d

I have java general path with random points. I want to crop one side of it and get straight line.
[image: crop general path]

How to make it?

Comment: What do you mean by crop one side of it?

Comment: Pardone moi, "cut" not "crop".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Create an `Area` based on the 1st `GeneralPath` based on [this constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Area.html#Area%28java.awt.Shape%29). I'll call it `mainArea`.
2. Create a `Rectangle2D` based on the line, covering the area to the left of it as well.  I'll call it `lineArea`.
3. Call [`Area.subtract(Area)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Area.html#subtract%28java.awt.geom.Area%29) using `mainArea.subtract(lineArea);`

An example can be seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10854490/418556).

[image]