# Java how to draw and fill a Polygon which has holes

Tags: java, awt, draw, polygon, jts

I am currently trying to draw and fill a Polygon which has a hole in it in Java. Normally this would not be a big problem, since I would draw the exterior ring and then draw the interior ring with the color of the background.

But the problem is, that the polygon is displayed above a image which should be "seen" through the hole.

I am writing the code in Java and am using [JTS Topology Suite](http://tsusiatsoftware.net/jts/main.html) for my geometry data.

This is my current code, which just paints the border and fills the polygon with a color.

```
private void drawPolygon(com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Polygon gpoly, Color color, Graphics2D g2d){

    java.awt.Polygon poly = (java.awt.Polygon)gpoly;

    for(Coordinate co : gpoly.getExteriorRing().getCoordinates() {
        poly.addPoint(co.x, co.y);
    }
    g2d.setColor(col);
    g2d.fill(poly);

    g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g2d.draw(poly);
}
```

Sadly [java.awt.Polygon](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Polygon.html) does not support Polygons with holes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Use the `Polygon` as the basis for an `Area` (e.g. called `polygonShape`).
- Create an `Ellipse2D` for the 'hole', then establish an `Area` for it (`ellipseShape`).
- Use [`Area.subtract(Area)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Area.html#subtract-java.awt.geom.Area-) something like:

  ```
  Area polygonWithHole = polygonShape.subtract(ellipseShape);
  ```

Comment: the holes in my polygons normally are also polygon-shaped and not ellipses, does it also work with your approach?

Comment: thanks for the friendly and fast answer. I currently cannot try and code your suggestion since I am not at my work pc. Yes I have read the documentation. I will post my results as soon I can get to coding

Comment: @AndrewThompson I completely agree, although I would have formulated the comment a bit friendlier. ;)

Comment: @brimborium  *"I would have formulated the comment a bit friendlier."*  Go for it.  I'm 'friendly' on FB.

Comment: yep this answer did it. thanks to you and brimborium for the help

Comment: *"yep this answer did it"*  Glad you got it sorted. And plus 1 for the initiative to 'pick up the ball and run with it'. *"thanks to you and brimborium for the help"*  Tip: Add @brimborium (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [java.awt.geom.Path2D](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Path2D.html) to render a "compound shape" with a hole in it:

- If you have `java.awt.Shape` objects defining the outside & inside edges of the shape, use `append(shape, false)` to add each shape.
- If you have a set of path points for the outside edge and a set of path points for the inside edge, use `lineTo()` to add the first set of points - creating a closed loop by either ending with the same point you started with, or calling `closePath()` to automatically close the loop. Then use `moveTo()` to create a break before adding the inner set of points via more `lineTo()` calls.

In either case, you **must** create the path passing `Path.WIND_NON_ZERO` to the constructor - otherwise the hole won't be left unfilled.

See [How to create shape with a hole?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19617238/how-to-create-shape-with-a-hole) for a longer code example.

Answer (score 1):

There are some ways to draw shapes or areas that are more complex than a simple polygon (another answer already mentioned `Area`).

Besides those, you could try to **tessellate** your final polygon. There are lots of algorithms to do this. For more complex shapes, the algorithms get a bit more complex as well. Basically, you're dividing your final shape into little polygons (usually triangles, but it also can be something else) and then draw those polygons.

You can take a look at your possibilities by searching for ***"Tessellation Algorithm"***, there are also some already implemented libraries for Java.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i will look into it. Using your approach would mean to tesselate every polygon every time i have to draw them though. I have around 30.000 polygons to draw on the screen of which like 100 have holes. Ill check out how this will affect the performance. Alternatively I have to save the tessellated versions of the polygons from the beginning in the class and draw this(i like this version better)

Comment: @LBecker I just put up this answer for completeness. I think I would rather work with `Area` or something similar. Thought that might affect performance as well. If performance is an issue, you will have to look at all your option and figure out which is the best.

Answer (score -1):

You could fill the polygon first, and then draw the holes on top, giving the illusion that it filled everything but the holes.

Comment: "But the problem is, that the polygon is displayed above a image which should be "seen" through the hole."

Comment: cheseaux is right, this sadly is not the correct answer :(

Comment: You would have to make a clipped section of the image and draw that over the polygon.

Comment: this would be a solution but i am looking for a way to draw the polygon correctly