# Get an Area containing the non-transparent pixels in a BufferedImage in Java

Tags: java, java-2d

In Java SE 7, I create a `BufferedImage` object:

```
BufferedImage i = new BufferedImage(300, 300, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics2D g = i.createGraphics();
```

And then I fill parts of the image with color, using several call to `fillPolygon`, `drawImage`, etc. (Note that some of my colors have an alpha less than 255.)

My question is, how can I construct an `Area` object which contains only the area which was painted to in the `BufferedImage`? From reading the API docs, I believe it could be done by inspecting the `Raster` returned by the `getAlphaRaster` method, but I'm hoping there's an easier (and faster?) way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ..how can I construct an `Area` object which contains only the area which was painted to in the `BufferedImage`?

The [`getOutline(..)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7218309/418556) method seen in this source could be used to distinguish between the opaque and translucent parts of the image.  Having said that, the method only checks for an 'exact match' between target color and image color for that pixel.  You'd need to adjust it to instead check for alpha <255.

[image]

The [`ShapeContainment`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13796268/418556) class would be used to determine if a point falls into any of a number of `Area` instances.

[image]

Other code deailing with Java-2D and images can be seen in [`OneRing`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10854490/418556) & [`ShapeCollision`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14575043/418556).

[image]

[image]

Comment: This looks really promising. Currently I'm doing the same thing you mentioned - just adding Shapes to an Area whenever I draw them, and it's a bit slow. I suspect your `getOutline` will solve my problem, with some modification. I'll try it in the next day or two and report back. :)