# Is there a function that converts any image into a circle of 150x150 pixels-java?

Tags: java, swing, resize, png, crop

I need a function/method that can mold(crop and resize) an imported (.png format) image into a circle of exact 150x150 pixels and it should keep transparency. I have searched all over internet, also I have my own code but I think its completely useless. I need this function for a code I am using to make GUI of a social-media app database.

```
private ImageIcon logo = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/test/test200x200.png"));
toCircle(logo);
```

I need the code for the following function:

```
public ImageIcon toCircle(ImageIcon icon)
{
    //code
    return icon;
 }
```

This function should convert this picture:

[image]

To this:

[image]

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code-request site. It is a question-and-answer site where you present problems that you face when programming, including all the research you have done and your best effort at the code, and we give an answer to your specific problem. Please read [ask].

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request for code rather than a question.

Comment: i am sorry i have my code but i thought it would make the question confusing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Create a new transparent image
- Get a `Graphics` object from the image.
- Set a clip for the graphics object.
- Paint the PNG format image.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10854490/418556) that uses a clipped region.

[image]

Comment: Hmm... the link provided links to this question Andrew :P

Comment: Yup the link fixed now :) 1+

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach, that might be more straight-forward to implement for this use case, is:

- Create a transparent `BufferedImage` the size of your icon
- Create `Graphics2D` from image, set hints for antialias
- Fill a circle the size of your background circle
- Draw the image on top of your circle, using [`AlphaComposite.SrcIn`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/compositing.html)

Something like:

```
public Icon toCircle(ImageIcon logo) {
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(150, 150); // Assuming logo 150x150
    Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();
    g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g.fillOval(1, 1, 148, 148); // Leaving some room for antialiasing if needed
    g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.SrcIn);
    g.drawImage(logo.getImage(), 0, 0, null);
    g.dispose();

    return new ImageIcon(image);
}
```